# What do we mean by Different JVMs

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, jvm

What do we mean by different JVMs? Does NETbeans IDE and Eclipse IDE use different JVM ?
If I am calling an application made using NETbeans from a client made using Eclipse IDE, then can we say that both application and client are running in diffrent JVM.

Comment: What do you mean by "application" and "client" here? The VM you happen to use when building the application is entirely irrelevant to the VM your code ends up running on. It's not like the app has a bundled VM...

Comment: every time you run a java program (even printing "Hello world"), it runs in a different VM. You IDE (if built in java) runs in a different VM and it has nothing to do with the VM in which your code runs

Comment: @Jon Skeet- I am creating a Ejb using netbeans IDE, glassfish server3.1.1. and ejb client using eclipse IDE, and trying to call ejb from ejb client. so can I say my ejb and ejb client are in different JVMs.

Comment: @RohitElayath: Yes, the client and the server will probably be in different VMs - but the IDE is irrelevant to that, other than when you're running as part of development.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Eclipse and Netbeans, you can define which JVM you want to use. If your JVM is compliant with the specs, it should work anyway. Different JVMs exist, like the official Oracle JVM, [JRockit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/jrockit/overview/index.html), or the [IBM JVM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/). They all follow the same specifications, but are different implementations.

To go further: A JVM (Java Virtual Machine) is only a part of a Java environment. To be able to run a Java program, you need to install a JRE (Java Runtime Environment), which is a JVM + standard libraries. And to develop, you need a JDK (Java Development Kit), which is a JRE with development tools, like the javac compiler, for example.

Comment: How can I define which JVM I want to use in these IDEs. and How can I see which JVM my IDE is using ?

Comment: I'm not using Netbeans to give you an answer for this IDE. For Eclipse, you can add different JDKs/JREs in Preferences->Java->Installed JREs.

Answer (score 3):

A JVM is a virtual machine capable of executing Java bytecode. Netbeans and Eclipse are IDE's used for development of Java based applications. You can select the JVM you want to use in each of the IDE's . There are different versions / implementations of JVM but derived from the same specifications

Comment: I just realized there different ways to understand the question... :-)

Comment: There is an exception: applets run in the same JVM.